# Login as another Member without the password

Tags: member-management

Using EE 2.x I had the ability as the Super Admin to click 'Login as Member' link from any member profile in the system and proceed to login as them without actually knowing their password. I've recently upgraded to EE3 and notice that the password is a required field when attempting to login as another Member. Is there anyway to disable that requirement and allow the Super Admin to login as any Member in the system without knowing their password?

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a fix from EllisLab support for the blank white page error when using the login as member feature on EE3. If anyone else runs into this try the following:

In system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Members/Profile/Login.php at line 192 add:

`$url = ee()->input->post('other');`

And change line 199 to read:

`elseif ($redirect == 'other' && ! empty($url))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to know the password of the user - EE is asking for your superadmin password, even though you are already logged in. This is just an additional security feature.

Comment: Thank you John, I should of thought to try that. I'd like to try this but I'm getting a blank white page now when I click the 'Login as...' link. I've opened up a ticket with EllisLab about it but they haven't been able to resolve it yet. I'm going to try reinstalling EE3 after I backup my templates. At any rate, thanks again for the tip!